# How to change routing in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have few images please have a look

Controller Name

[image: Tags Controller name]

Action Name with paramteres

[image: Action Name with paramters]

Routing

[image: Routing]

I Just show image to clearify the names of controller and action etc etc . Now at current situation when i make a call to

`tags/1`   it goes to Index action of tag controller

which is fine , now i want that in future my url looks like this

`/tags/Coupons-1.html` here `1` is `pageno` and  this will update every time

How can i do this

Thanks in advance and please ask if you need anything else .

Comment: @downvoter , i think you should care to explain before downvote .

Comment: seems like you already answered your own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that:

Change your route as follow:

```
routes.MapRoute(
              name: "Tags",
              url: "tags/{pageno}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Tags", action = "Index"
              , pageno = UrlParameter.Optional }
          );
```

Pat attention that i change the `pageno` parameter to `string`

**The controller**

```
 public ActionResult Index(string pageno)
 {
   Do Something
 }
```

Now in the controller you should do:

- If the parameter is `NULL` do something
- Next try to parse the parameter to `Int`, if so then you know you got `tags/1`
- If its not an `Int` then you probably got something like that `/tags/Coupons-1.html` in this case pull out the page number from the parameter

Comment: Thanks it really help , i was forgetting to change int to string . Thanks again